# How long was Boba Fett sentenced to in prison?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, boba-fett

In the season 2 finale of *The Clone Wars*, Boba Fett is arrested by the Republic and, as we later see, sent to prison for his crimes.  He is seen in season 4, about to escape.  My question is: do we know how long Boba was sentenced to be in prison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace* is set in 32 BBY; *Episode II: Attack of the Clones*, 22 BBY; and *Episode III: Revenge of the Sith is in 19 BBY*.

All seven (non-chronological) seasons of The Clone Wars take place within a three-year period.

As the question notes: Boba Fett is captured by the Jedi in the final episode of the second season of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*. The only time we see him in prison is in episode “Deception” (15th episode of the 4th season of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*); however, it’s as he is about to get out.

This time period covers the following episodes:

- 222 - Lethal Trackdown (**Captured by the Jedi**)
- 305 - Corruption
- 306 - The Academy
- 307 - Assassin
- 302 - ARC Troopers
- 304 - Sphere of Influence
- 308 - Evil Plans
- 122 - Hostage Crisis
- 309 - Hunt for Ziro
- 310 - Heroes on Both Sides
- 311 - Pursuit of Peace
- 215 - Senate Murders
- 312 - Nightsisters
- 313 - Monster
- 314 - Witches of the Mist
- 315 - Overlords
- 316 - Altar of Mortis
- 317 - Ghosts of Mortis
- 318 - The Citadel
- 319 - Counterattack
- 320 - Citadel Rescue
- 321 - Padawan Lost
- 322 - Wookiee Hunt
- 401 - Water War
- 402 - Gungan Attack
- 403 - Prisoners
- 404 - Shadow Warrior
- 405 - Mercy Mission
- 406 - Nomad Droids
- 407 - Darkness on Umbara
- 408 - The General
- 409 - Plan of Dissent
- 410 - Carnage of Krell
- 411 - Kidnapped
- 412 - Slaves of the Republic
- 413 - Escape from Kadavo
- 414 - A Friend In Need
- 415 - Deception (**Escapes Incarceration**)

We don’t know exactly how long he was *sentenced* — primarily because details of his experience with the criminal justice system (arraignment, prosecution, sentencing, and transfer to prison, etc.) are scarce — but he was in custody roughly 9 months, about 58% of the year BBY20 to BBY19, plus a little time from his capture to the Senate murders.

Consequently, because he appears to escape before his sentence has ended, we know he was likely sentenced to longer than this time, otherwise he would have been let out before “Deception.”